# How to Pass multiple parameters from C# to crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I used this cod for pass a parameter to CR but can't pass multiple parameters!!!
how to change this code for pass multiple parameters from C# to crystal reports?

```
ReportDocument cryRpt1 = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt1.Load("C:\\Users\\BilgiSoft\\Desktop\\RPTLetter1.rpt");

ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = comboBox1.Text;
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["My Parameter"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

crParameterValues.Clear();
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt1;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: You can use [SetParameterValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms226143(v=vs.90).aspx) method, as many times as many parameters you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt1 = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt1.Load("C:\\Users\\BilgiSoft\\Desktop\\RPTLetter1.rpt");

ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
//Add first param
ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["My Parameter"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = comboBox1.Text;
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);

//add second param
ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["My Parameter 2"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = comboBox2.Text;
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt1;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: What if i have like 2 or more subreports? how to i assign them using your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (ReportDocument crReport in crArrReport)
            {
                foreach (ParameterField pfield in crReport.ParameterFields)
                {
                    pfield.EnableAllowMultipleValue = true;
                    if (paramFields.IndexOf(pfield) < 0)
                        paramFields.Add(pfield);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.